# Initializing an array of structs in C using Macros with an array parameter

Tags: c, arrays

I am attempting to use a macro to initialize all the array parameters of a structure array where one of the parameters is an array.

My struct is

```
typedef struct
{
  int size_parts;
  int *parts;
  int width;
  int length;
} parts_struct;
```

And my macro is defined as

```
#define SET_ARRAY_INPUT(_width, _length, ...) {width:_width, length:_length, parts:{__VA_ARGS__}, size_parts:(sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int))}
```

My array is initialized as

```
static parts_struct parts[] = {
   SET_ARRAY_INPUT(2, 3, 9354, 39458, 3294),
   SET_ARRAY_INPUT(4, 2, 9354, 3294)
}
```

However this is always failing and I keep getting error "error: braces around scalar initializer for type". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't valid C. Rather looks like some icky macro used by a C++ constructor. Please don't write code like this regardless of language used... Now what you actually want (in C) is probably a compound literal.

Comment: A guess - mayby use double brackets around the MACRO SET_ARRAY - ie SET_ARRAY(( 2,3,4,5 )),

Comment: Do you have advice on how to get a similar behavior ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)? Like Lundin already mentioned, this looks more like JavaScript than C.

Comment: @Groo: It's a GCC extension syntax that GCC documents as obsolete since GCC 2.5 (meaning it was obsolete by mid-1994, possibly as early as late-1993).  See my answer for links to supporting evidence.  I only found it out today when trying to work out how the macro in the question could work at all.

Comment: @Lundin: It's using an antique GCC extension syntax, long since obsolete.  See my answer for links to supporting evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your macro, you're trying to initialize a pointer like an array:

```
parts:{__VA_ARGS__}
```

You need to add the compound literal syntax to this:

```
parts:(int []){__VA_ARGS__}
```

Comment: Seems to have done something. Now I cam getting an error "unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported".

Comment: @user1936582 It compiles and runs for me.  What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: Go it to work thank you! Had moved some stuff while testing and forgot to put it back to normal.

Comment: Note that the 'designated initializer' notation used in the question is a GCC extension that has been obsolete since 'GCC 2.5' (see my answer for links), meaning since not later than 1994-07-14 (when 2.6.0 was released).

Answer (score 1):

In standard C (C99 or C11), designated initializers in a structure are preceded by a `.` and use `=` instead of `:`.  You might manage to get something like this to work:

```
#define SET_ARRAY_INPUT(_width, _length, ...) \
    { .width = (_width), .length = (_length), \
      .parts = (int []){__VA_ARGS__}, \
      .size_parts = (sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int))}
```

Note that the GCC manual page on [Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits) states:

> Another syntax that has the same meaning, obsolete since GCC 2.5, is `fieldname:`, as shown here:
>
> ```
> struct point p = { y: yvalue, x: xvalue };
> ```

Thus the alternative definition shown below does work (to my considerable surprise) but it is a GCC extension that has officially been obsolete for a very long time (the GCC [releases](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) page says GCC 2.5.0 was released in 1993-10-22; GCC 2.5.8 was released 1994-01-24; GCC 2.6.0 was released 1994-07-14) — and should not be used in new or refurbished code:

```
#define SET_ARRAY_INPUT(_width, _length, ...) \
    { width: (_width), length: (_length), \
      parts: (int []){__VA_ARGS__}, \
      size_parts: (sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int))}
```

Comment: It is telling me " error: expected primary-expression before '.' token"

Comment: The `.parts` is a pointer, not an array, so the initializer needs a compound literal.  The amended answer compiles.

Comment: `parts_struct p = SET_ARRAY_INPUT(2, 3, 9354, 39458, 3294);` works well for me.